# 22.04.3 - flashing "anti" sign

Tags: display, usb-c

I just rebooted my laptop after updates.  I now have an "anti" sign flashing on and off in the middle of the screen towards the bottom.  I tried to get a screenshot, but it disappears when I start to take one.  Laptop is a Lenovo X1 connected to a USB-C docking station

Comment: Check for spurious keypresses, or signals from a weak USB cable or hub that might be interpreted as spurious keypresses.